# FCM в какой-то момент перестают ходить уведомления

Tags: android, fcm

Доброго времени суток !

Если приложением не пользовались несколько дней и после отправить ему пуш то он не приходит, бэк при этом говорит что все успешно отправлено

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2022 06:45:00 GMT
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Последующие пуши тоже не приходят

Далее загружаю приложение под отладчиком (Android Studio), отправляю ему пуш и все начинает прекрасно приходить

Токен девайса не менялся, т.е. какой был в бд бэка до запуска под отладчиком такой и остался

Подскажите, как отловить этот баг ? или может что-то нужно периодически делать ? например "пинг-понг" пару раз в день отправлять или ещё что ...

Comment: может у вас обработка пушей хромает, попробуйте отправить с бэка себе пуш и без отладки.

Comment: так я и так сам себе отправляю. и обработки по сути никакой, только показ нотификации. и повторюсь, пуши не ходили, я зашел под отладкой, начали ходить, отключаю смарт от компа и они продолжают ходить. если активности несколько дней не будет то перестанут

Comment: Это на всех устройствах, или только у вас такое?

Comment: приложение пока в разработке, так что можно сказать только у меня :) если поможет то Redmi Note 10T 12 android

Comment: странно что токен не обновляется, fcm токены обновляются вообще и там даже метод есть такой

Comment: то что редко это норма. судя по докам обновляется при новой установке, при очистке данных приложения и если мне не изменяет память если в течении месяца не было активности у приложения

Comment: @Bodigard, скорее всего ограничения ОС накладывает на обработку пушей во имя экономии заряда и сети. Покопайтесь в системных настройках режима работы приложения - там могут быть варианты, в которых ОС принудительно приложение закрывает. Также ОС может отзывать всякие разрешения у долго неиспользуемых приложений. Например с 13 андроида на уведомления нужно разрешение и оно будет отозвано после неиспользования.